# Cleanest way to filter a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Python:

```
pd.read_csv("CME-datasets-codes.csv", header=None)
```

Produces:

```
    0               1
0   CME/OH2014      Oats Futures, March 2014, OH2014, CBOT
1   CME/HGG2004     Copper Futures, February 2004, HGG2004, COMEX
2   CME/BRH2014     Brazilian Real (BRL/USD) Futures, March 2014, ...
3   CME/F5H2014     PJM PPL Zone Off-Peak Calendar-Month Day-Ahead...
4   CME/PDMU2016    MISO Indiana Hub Day-Ahead Peak Calendar-Month...
```

I want to filter this to show me all rows that start with "CME/C" in column 0.

What's the cleanest way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
df[df[0].str.startswith('CME/C')]
```

Comment: It may be necessary to quote the column name `df[df['0'].str.startswith('CME/C')]`

Comment: It won't be, as the OP reads in a csv using the `header=None` option, which means pandas will number the columns using integers. `df['0']` will throw an error.

Comment: Alternative is use `loc` - `df[df.loc[:, 0].str.startswith('CME/C')]`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df[df.0.str[:5]=="CME/C"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The easy and ugly route is

`df[df['column_name'] == value]`

At first sight, this can only catch equalities, but in reality, any vectorised function technically can be applied over this. As such, you can use:

`df[df['column_name'].str.startswith('CME\/C')]`

There are other methods, such as masking, that look a little more elegant. They are, however, neither more effective nor necessarily worth it. Sometimes, ugly is the way to go ;)